# sftp to use password stored in a parameter file

Tags: shell-script, password, sftp

Is it possible to to connect two servers through sftp with a batch of commands and where the authenticating password needs to be read from a file (where it is stored previously)? I am new in the UNIX world, please help me on this.

Comment: Use `expect` http://www.linux-bsd-central.com/index.php/content/view/26/29/

Answer (score 1):

You can also use password less connections, just use public/private key and you are ready to go.

Using `lftp` client you can establish connections giving username/password as a parameter in the command line `lftp sftp://sftp_server -uuser,password`

Comment: While not answering the question per se, it is what the OP should be doing as `expect` is just crazy when you can use keys

Comment: @gwillie the question was answered in the previous answer. Reason for me to start with "You can **also** use...". Anyway, `lftp` parameters can be read from a batch file and that may answer the question with a different solution than the previous one.